# C# WPF StartupEvent get path

Tags: c#, wpf

My objective is that when I open a file with a specific extension it will open my program in C#. That part is done but now I want to get the path of the file that I clicked on previously.

This is just the main code of **App.xaml.cs**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Logique d'interaction pour App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here are my two commands to associate my extension to my program.

```
    ftype GDevDB=N:\Divers\GDevDB\bin\Debug\GDevDB.exe "%1"
    assoc .GDevDB=GDevDB
```

Solution :

I've put the command in a batch file and the %1 was the one of the batch file and it was returning an empty string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() If you need those somewhere else. Index 0 is the path to your program. Index 1 is the file you are looking for

Comment: Index 1 is returning me an empty string and not the name of the file

Comment: How do you call your program?

Comment: By opening my file with my extension which calls the program

Comment: Can you pls Post some Code how you Pass The File als commandline arg?

Comment: `ftype GDevDB=N:\Divers\GDevDB\bin\Debug\GDevDB.exe "%1" assoc .GDevDB=GDevDB`

Comment: Can you  check the content of the array returned from getcommandlineargs?

Comment: I get the full path of my program and then an empty string

Comment: then I would think that the "ftype" command is not working correctly. as far as I can see u passed multiple arguments. if none is passed to your program ftype does not work as expected

Comment: I just see now that I've just done a mistake by putting these 2 commands in a .bat file and the %1 take the argument of the batch file ... But thanks you anyways if you were not there I wouldn't have find my error :D

Answer (score 0):

The file you clicked on will be in the first command line argument. The arguments are in the array of strings `e.Args`, in the `StartupEventArgs`. For the file you clicked on, you thus need to get `e.Args[0]`.

Comment: I just tested this but It return me an empty string it hasn't return me the path of the file

Comment: This is weird (also that `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`gives you an empty string). How did you get the file to be opened by your c# program? And what do you get when you call the program from command line, giving a file as argument?

Comment: I've done this to associate my extension : `ftype GDevDB=N:\Divers\GDevDB\bin\Debug\GDevDB.exe "%1"
assoc .GDevDB=GDevDB`

Comment: It returns me only the full path and not the empty string like before. Only 1 argument

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
 public partial class App : Application
        {
            private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
            {
                foreach (string arg in e.Args)
                {
                    //Do something
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm just getting an empty string